# Android: How to mock Location Service

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I try to implement some app and I need to implement my own LocationService, that will be run for an original Location Service. I have an MockProvider and I want that my LocationService make it for all apps on my device the MockProvider as that provider for GPS. I think it must be the same, what also the apps like "Location Spoofer" or "Fake GPS Location" do and I also know that my programm must be copied in system/app(my android device is rooted).
My question is how can I implement this LocationService and how can I change my LocationService with original?